# How to estimate the location of a transmitter signal from radio telemetry data using two bearings?

Tags: r, triangulation

I am new to R and I am trying to find a method that allows me to estimate the location of a transmitter signal using telemetry data. However for each signal I have only two bearings. I tried using the sigloc package in R. I can easily calculate intersects with this package, however when I try to calculate locations I get an error message (see below). When I artificially create a dataset with three bearings, I can easily calculate locations. Does this mean I cannot calculate locations using only two bearings with sigloc? And if so is there another package/method that would allow me to do that? Below is a subset of my data and script using sigloc:

```
Date<- c(08/02/2017,08/02/2017,08/02/2017,08/02/2017,08/02/2017,08/02/2017)

Time<- c(0.8013888889,0.8013888889,0.8027777778,0.8027777778,0.8708333333,0.8708333333)

Easting<-c(623235,623240,623220,623214,623701,623842)

Northing<-c(838644,838653,838627,838678,839005,838954)

Azimuth<-c(240,268,260,312,231,122)

GID<-c(1,1,2,2,3,3)

df<-data.frame(Date,Time,Easting,Northing,Azimuth,GID)

library(sigloc)

bats<-as.receiver(df)

plot(bats,bearings=TRUE,xlab="Easting",ylab="Northing")

intersectBats<-findintersects(bats)

intersectBats
GID        X        Y
1    1 623251.3 838653.4

2    1       NA       NA

3    1 623251.3 838653.4

4    1       NA       NA

5    1       NA       NA

6    1       NA       NA

7    2 623262.3 838634.5

8    2       NA       NA

9    2 623262.3 838634.5

10   2       NA       NA

11   2       NA       NA

12   2       NA       NA

13   3 623726.9 839025.9

14   3       NA       NA

15   3 623726.9 839025.9

16   3       NA       NA

17   3       NA       NA

18   3       NA       NA


plot(intersectBats,xlab="Easting",ylab="Northing")


loc<-locate(bats)
Error in nleqslv(c(start_point_x, start_point_y), solver) : 
  'x' contains a non-finite value at index=1
```

Comment: I know nothing about `sigloc`. The error message is clear enough: non-finite starting values are being passed to `nleqslv`. Looking at your data `intersectBats`  there are a lot of `NA` entries which must have something to do with data `bats`.  I wouldn't know how to correct that but I can advise you to mail the maintainer of `sigloc` to **test** the termination code of `nleqslv` for errors.

Comment: Additionally: `sigloc` should inspect the starting values it passes to `nleqslv` for non-finiteness if one doesn't want to get error messages as in shown.